# Nested variable calls

Tags: django, django-templates

Can something like this be done in django?

```
{% for item in lst %}
    {{ something_{{ item }} }}
{% endfor %}
```

Args passed to render would be for example:

```
{"lst": range(3), "something_0": "aaa", "something_1": "aaa", "something_2": "aaa"}
```

Comment: You should probably accept Daniel's answer by the way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Structure your data as a list of dicts.

```
[
    {'something': 'aaa', 'something_else': 'bbb', ...},
    {'something': 'ccc', 'something_else': 'ddd', ...},
    ...
]
```

and now:

```
{% for item in lst %}
    {{ item.something }}
    {{ item.something_else }}
{% endfor %}
```